# How to configure wifi connection via ONVIF

Tags: ip-camera, onvif

I'm working on camera firmware (ONVIF services). I've found network interface configuration methods (Section 5.3) in [ONVIF developer guide](http://www.openipcam.com/files/ONVIF/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmer's_Guide.pdf), but is it possible to configure wifi networks connection?

I need to:

1. get available wifi networks
2. choose wifi network

Does ONVIF describe such methods web-service should implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is described in the [core specification](http://www.onvif.org/specs/core/ONVIF-Core-Spec-v210.pdf) (section 8.2.22, page 64).

For 1., the method is [ScanAvailableDot11Networks](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl#op.ScanAvailableDot11Networks)

For 2., [SetNetworkInterfaces](http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl#op.SetNetworkInterfaces) will use the Extension.Dot11 elements.

You also have to implement a few other methods, such as GetDot11Status and GetDot11Capabilities, and return correct information in GetNetworkInterfaces.